# Does "jzmq" support ZeroMQ Version 3?

Tags: java, zeromq, jzmq

anyone knows if the java bindings "jzmq" for ZeroMQ work with ZeroMQ version 3.x.x ? There is NOWEHERE official information about that. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, not easy to find. However, browsing around in the jzmq code, it seems that 3.0 (and possibly higher) versions are supported. Have a look at the following java file, it contains notions about 3.0 including various checks for current zmq version and appropriate handling (e.g. supporting newer zmq 3.0+ functionality):

https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/blob/master/src/org/zeromq/ZMQ.java

For example (line 813 per 2013-01-31):

```
/**
* @since 3.0.0
*/
public void setSndHWM (long sndHWM) {
    if (ZMQ.version_full() < ZMQ.make_version(3, 0, 0))
        return;

    setLongSockopt (SNDHWM, sndHWM);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any problems when using the [Mule](https://github.com/claudemamo/mule-transport-zeromq) & [Apache CXF](https://github.com/claudemamo/cxf-rt-transports-zeromq) ZeroMQ transports with ZeroMQ 3.2.2 and [jzmq 2.1.0](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/tree/2.1.0). Having said that, I don't know if jzmq, underneath, is calling methods deprecated in ZeroMQ 3.2.2.